# Error loading extension

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I got this extension for google chrome and it won't load when I try to load unpacked extension. Where is the problem?

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "HTML",
  "description": "HTML change",
  "version": "1", 

  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },  
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://ocjene.skole.hr/pocetna/prijava/*"],
    }
  ],
}
```

Comment: What error message do you get? Json shouldn't have a trailing comma on last but one row. Try that first. edit - oh and end-4 row

Answer (score 0):

Trailing commas mean invalid json - try this change first:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "HTML",
  "description": "HTML change",
  "version": "1", 

  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },  
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://ocjene.skole.hr/pocetna/prijava/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [Can't load unpacked extension?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chromebook-central/LktMohcu8yI) forum.

> I'm going to recommend that you start with a powerwash. This will wipe your device and return it to factory settings (and also put you back to the stable channel). Full instructions can be found in [this help center article](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/183084?hl=en).
>
> After the powerwash, I would suggest that you test whether or not the extension will load while still running a stable build. If it does, and then it stops working when you switch o the dev channel, that helps to narrow down the issue.

Additional references:

- [Load Unpacked Extension](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chromebook-central/PU5MmSgH__E/_BR7IGAaAwAJ)
- [Unable to load unpacked extensions](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/ovxU2J1veOc)